Drools NullPointer at ConditionEvaluator
We are having a very weird bug when using drools in our spring boot application.
I am not quite sure how to debug the problem to get to the root cause.
We are in the process of creating a new project in order to update it to spring boot.
The previous project stil runs in production without issues with the same drl files.
The error we are getting is the folowing one:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error evaluating constraint '!getEPresEnabled()' in []
    at org.drools.core.rule.constraint.MvelConstraint.evaluate(MvelConstraint.java:262)
    at org.drools.core.rule.constraint.MvelConstraint.isAllowed(MvelConstraint.java:215)
    at org.drools.core.phreak.PhreakFromNode.isAllowed(PhreakFromNode.java:300)
    at org.drools.core.phreak.PhreakFromNode.checkConstraintsAndPropagate(PhreakFromNode.java:289)
    at org.drools.core.phreak.PhreakFromNode.doLeftInserts(PhreakFromNode.java:120)
    at org.drools.core.phreak.PhreakFromNode.doNode(PhreakFromNode.java:68)
    at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleNetworkEvaluator.evalNode(RuleNetworkEvaluator.java:355)
    at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleNetworkEvaluator.innerEval(RuleNetworkEvaluator.java:301)
    at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleNetworkEvaluator.outerEval(RuleNetworkEvaluator.java:136)
    at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleNetworkEvaluator.evaluateNetwork(RuleNetworkEvaluator.java:94)
    at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleExecutor.reEvaluateNetwork(RuleExecutor.java:194)
    at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleExecutor.evaluateNetworkAndFire(RuleExecutor.java:73)
    at org.drools.core.common.DefaultAgenda.fireNextItem(DefaultAgenda.java:970)
    at org.drools.core.common.DefaultAgenda.fireLoop(DefaultAgenda.java:1312)
    at org.drools.core.common.DefaultAgenda.fireAllRules(DefaultAgenda.java:1251)
    at org.drools.core.impl.StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.internalFireAllRules(StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.java:1359)
    at org.drools.core.impl.StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.fireAllRules(StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.java:1350)
    at org.drools.core.impl.StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.fireAllRules(StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.java:1331)

    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:793)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:708)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:793)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:708)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1070)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:517)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:584)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:111)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:337)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:122)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:109)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:198)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.java:146)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:112)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:82)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:221)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:186)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:117)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.SendErrorPageHandler.handleRequest(SendErrorPageHandler.java:52)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:275)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:79)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:134)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:255)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:79)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:100)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:387)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:852)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2019)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1558)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1449)
    at org.xnio.XnioWorker$WorkerThreadFactory$1$1.run(XnioWorker.java:1282)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at ConditionEvaluator01b78c2100ed472382459f04764abdea.evaluate(Unknown Source)
    at org.drools.core.rule.constraint.MvelConstraint.evaluate(MvelConstraint.java:260)
    ... 172 common frames omitted

I though the error was null field inside the object when executing the rule. However, I have logged the object before and I also checked using debug that the field is trying to access is not null.
The error only starts to appear after invoking 10 times the same ruleGroup. For the first 9 times the rule engine works perfectly.
The spesific rule that is causing the issue is :
RuleImage
We are loading the drools using the code below:
@Configuration
@AutoConfigureAfter({ApplicationContext.class})
public class DroolsConfig {
private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DroolsConfig.class);

    @Autowired
    public  ResourcePatternResolver resourcePatternResolver;
    
    @Autowired
    private  ApplicationContext context;
    
    
    @Getter
    private static Map<RuleGroups, KieBase> kieContainerMap = new HashMap<>();
    
    
    @Bean("DroolKieContainer")
    public DroolsRuleEngine kieContainer() throws IOException {
        loadRules();
        return new DroolsRuleEngine(kieContainerMap);
    }
    
    @Bean("kiePostProcessor")
    public KModuleBeanFactoryPostProcessor kiePostProcessor() {
        return new KModuleBeanFactoryPostProcessor();
    }
    
    private void loadRules() throws IOException {
        kieContainerMap = new HashMap<>();
        final KieServices kieServices = KieServices.Factory.get();
        KieFileSystem kieFileSystem = kieServices.newKieFileSystem();
        KieModuleModel kieModuleModel = kieServices.newKieModuleModel();
        for (RuleGroups ruleGroups : RuleGroups.values()) {
            Resource[] resources = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver().getResources("classpath*:" + findSpringBootArtifactName().replaceAll("\\.", "/") + "/rules/" + ruleGroups.getName().split("-")[0] + "/" + ruleGroups.getName().split("-")[1] + "/*.drl");
            Arrays.asList(resources).forEach(r -> {
                try {
                    kieFileSystem.write(
                            "src/main/resources/" + r.getURI().toString().substring(r.getURI().toString().lastIndexOf("/classes/") + 9)
                            , ResourceFactory.newFileResource(r.getFile()).setResourceType(ResourceType.DRL));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            });
        }
    
        for (RuleGroups ruleGroups : RuleGroups.values()) {
            String rulePackage = findSpringBootArtifactName() + ".rules." + ruleGroups.getName().split("-")[0] + "." + ruleGroups.getName().split("-")[1];
            kieModuleModel.newKieBaseModel(ruleGroups.getName())
                    .addPackage(rulePackage);
        }
        kieFileSystem.writeKModuleXML(kieModuleModel.toXML());
    
        KieBuilder kb = kieServices.newKieBuilder(kieFileSystem);
        kb.buildAll();
        Results results = kb.getResults();
        if (results.hasMessages(Message.Level.ERROR)) {
            log.error("[DROOLS] " + results.getMessages());
        }
        KieModule kieModule = kb.getKieModule();
        KieContainer kieContainer = kieServices.newKieContainer(kieModule.getReleaseId());
        kieContainer.getKieBaseNames().forEach(k -> {
            kieContainerMap.put(RuleGroups.getByName(k), kieContainer.getKieBase(k));
        });
    }
    
    
    private String findSpringBootArtifactName() {
        try {
            return Class.forName(Arrays.stream(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()).filter(c -> c.getClassName().endsWith("App")).findFirst().get().getClassName()).getPackageName();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

Basically we have a folder structure that contains the differrent drls based on the differnt actions
image: Folder structure
Each "RuleGroup" is a different folder and runs only one drl file.
In order to validate and run the drools we are using the code below


public void validate(Object model, RuleGroups group) throws Throwable {
        if (!kieContainerMap.containsKey(group)) {
            throw new Exception("Group: " + group + " rule file not found");
        }
        KieSession kieSession = kieContainerMap.get(group).newKieSession();

        List<Object> errors = new ArrayList<>();

        kieSession.setGlobal("errors", errors);

        if (model instanceof Collection) {
            ((Collection) model).stream().forEach(c -> {
                if (c != null) {
                    kieSession.insert(c);
                }
            });
        } else {
            kieSession.insert(model);
        }
        try {
            kieSession.getObjects().forEach(object -> {
                try {
                    log.debug("[DROOLS] Before checking drools {}", new ObjectMapper().registerModule(new JavaTimeModule()).disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS)
                            .writeValueAsString(object));
                } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                    log.error("[DROOLS] " + e.getMessage(), e);
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("[DROOLS] " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        kieSession.fireAllRules();

        kieSession.dispose();

        if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
            throw (Throwable) errors.get(0);
        }
    }

Each time we need to validate something we pass the Object plus the rule group we want to run, create a new kiesession, insert the model and fire the rule.
I have tried different drool versions, different java versions, trying to load the drl files differently with no luck.

Please don't post images of code. Have you tried refactoring that constraint to be DocMedicine( getEPresEnabled() == false ) from m ?

I remember a bug when somethnig == false was misbehaving but false == something was working fine because of the dsl parser issues of complex conditions with braces. But first could you check whether m collection doesn't contain nulls?

@Mike
I am starting to think that is a parser issue. I just cannot understand why it needs 9 different sessions for the problem to arise.
RoddyoftheFrozenPeas suggestion seems to bypass the specific rule and go to the next. Some of the rules that have something instead of something == true, are causing a null pointer after 9 sessions

@Akis, if problem is intermittent (needs 9 session to fail the rule which was working 8 times) then this is definitely not parser issue otherwise it will behave the same way each time. Are you working in concurrent (multithreaded) environment? If so, Drools code is not thread safe in many cases. Could you try synchronize any drools objects access other than facts evaluation?

@Mike I am not sure what do you mean. The "my" DroolRuleEngine bean that creates the kieBase I a singleton bean. Sping boot creates different threads for the incoming requests. But I believe the same thread handles the transaction and the drool rule check. In every new request a new kieSession is created and the object is passed to the engine. Except, if the engine inside uses different thread?  Can you give a bit more information what should I check for synchronize any drools objects?

It seems that using the parameter -Ddrools.jittingThreshold=-1 fixes the problem. I am not quite sure why though.

@Akis, thanks for sharing!

the issue back to 2012 related to mvel and JIT in drools
